# images are not saved by load_file('path') in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

when i tried to insert a image (for BLOB)into mysql database in workbench through load_file('c:\path..\iamge.jpg') it shows query is completed but image is not saved to database it show null value in image column

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in MySQL documentation for load_file():
“To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege. The file must be readable by the server and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory. (Prior to MySQL 8.0.17, the file must be readable by all, not just readable by the server.)

If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns NULL.“

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file